# How to handle firewall restrictions while building chat apps?

Tags: network-programming, xmpp, chat

I am building a simple chat application using a jabber based server. The clients are expected to connect over port 5222. But, when i was testing my app, I found that in some networks access is limited to port 80 or 8080 only.

I have came across a couple of solutions:

a) Use BOSH - but found it to be slow and flaky on mobile devices.

b) I was just wondering what if i make my jabber server listen on port 80 - (Not sure what would be the implications of this!)

I wanted to know your thoughts on above solutions and know how to make my app universally accessible like other chat applications like gtalk , fb-chat etc.

Edit:
Also, would there be any other firewall restrictions that i might be missing?

Comment: Use port 80, just don't try to set anything else up for that port on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Use BOSH over HTTPS (port 443/tcp).  Getting BOSH implemented well is a little tricky, but it can certainly be done.  Use a different [XMPP library](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Otherwise, use port 443/tcp, and use the old-style TLS-handshake-first mechanism that we used to use for encryption, rather than Start-TLS.  Some network middle-boxes will mess with your traffic on port 80/tcp if it doesn't look like HTTP.  Likewise, some middle-boxes will not allow your connection on 443/tcp if the first several network packets don't look like a SSL or TLS handshake.